# Text Scrolling in java

Tags: java

Pleae help to solve this problem... I has a page designed in JFrames
Now i need to make a text scrolling at the top of the page.... Please provide me the code...

Comment: "Please provide me the code..."  Please have a seat while we whip up some code for you.  Oh, and help yourself to coffee and donuts while you're waiting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, is is commented and will most likely help you.

http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/java/ta_scroll/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this thread may be of interest to you: [Creating A Scrolling Marquee](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/java/62861/62861/creating-a-scrolling-marquee/)

Answer (score 1):

```
   ScrollText s=   new ScrollText("ello Everyone.");
   jLabel3.add(s);//add it to jLabel


     public class ScrollText extends JComponent {
      private BufferedImage image;
      private Dimension imageSize;
      private volatile int currOffset;
      private Thread internalThread;
      private volatile boolean noStopRequested;
      public ScrollText(String text) {
       currOffset = 0;
       buildImage(text);
       setMinimumSize(imageSize);
       setPreferredSize(imageSize);
       setMaximumSize(imageSize);
       setSize(imageSize);
       noStopRequested = true;
       Runnable r = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
        try {
        runWork();
       } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
      } 
     }
   };

   internalThread = new Thread(r, "ScrollText");
   internalThread.start();
   }

     private void buildImage(String text) {
     RenderingHints renderHints = new RenderingHints(
     RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

     renderHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
     RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

     BufferedImage scratchImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1,
     BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

     Graphics2D scratchG2 = scratchImage.createGraphics();
     scratchG2.setRenderingHints(renderHints);

     Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 24);

     FontRenderContext frc = scratchG2.getFontRenderContext();
     TextLayout tl = new TextLayout(text, font, frc);
     Rectangle2D textBounds = tl.getBounds();
     int textWidth = (int) Math.ceil(textBounds.getWidth());
     int textHeight = (int) Math.ceil(textBounds.getHeight());

      int horizontalPad = 600;
      int verticalPad = 10;

       imageSize = new Dimension(textWidth + horizontalPad, textHeight
       + verticalPad);

       image = new BufferedImage(imageSize.width, imageSize.height,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHints(renderHints);

       int baselineOffset = (verticalPad / 2) - ((int) textBounds.getY());

      g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       g2.fillRect(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

      g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
       tl.draw(g2, 0, baselineOffset);

            // Free-up resources right away, but keep "image" for
            // animation.
       scratchG2.dispose();
       scratchImage.flush();
       g2.dispose();
   }
         public void paint(Graphics g) {
         // Make sure to clip the edges, regardless of curr size
            g.setClip(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

            int localOffset = currOffset; // in case it changes
             g.drawImage(image, -localOffset, 0, this);
              g.drawImage(image, imageSize.width - localOffset, 0, this);

                       g.setColor(Color.black);
             g.drawRect(0, 0, imageSize.width - 1, imageSize.height - 1);
         }
                 private void runWork() {
                while (noStopRequested) {
               try {
                  Thread.sleep(10); // 10 frames per second

                       // adjust the scroll position
                          currOffset = (currOffset + 1) % imageSize.width;

                             // signal the event thread to call paint()
                            repaint();
                          } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                               Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                      }          
                  }
                  }

             public void stopRequest() {
               noStopRequested = false;
               internalThread.interrupt();
                    }

                public boolean isAlive() {
                   return internalThread.isAlive();
                          }
                  }
```